# Magento: Add button to cart view

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I like to add a button to my cart view. I also like to implement the business-logic myself, that gets triggered when the button is pressed.

How can I do that?

Comment: You'll need to make a new [module and controller](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a block with your button to the checkout.cart.methods & checkout.cart.top_methods blocks using checkout.xml layout

Comment: wo genau finde ich die XML, bzw. die pthml?

Comment: oh, sorry: where exactly can I find the xml?

Comment: I don't know exactly what interface/theme you're using, but by default it is in base/default/layout/checkout.xml

Comment: First of all: thanks, I was able to found the XML. Second: Could you please give some more information on what I am supposed to add in this XML-File and where exactly I am supposed to add the .phtml-file?

Comment: You should have a look to the Magento designer guide, which is available on the Magento website. Anyway, I've already told you that you should add a block in the checkout.cart.methods & checkout.cart.top_methods, and this block may (or not, depends of what you want to do) be of type core/template, and you can specify the template path